# Validation Attributes: Keep them when updating model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

When I have to use validation attributes for my Entity Framework models I usually copy and past the model properties into another class and give metadata to the EF model. For example:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EntityXModel))]
public partial class EntityX {

    public String Name {get; set;}
}

public class EntityXModel{

   [Required]
   public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

This approach has a problem and that is if I update my .edmx file, all matadata will be lost. So I can do a trick and make the `EntityXModel` convertible to that class like

```
public class EntityXModel{

   [Required]
   public String Name {get; set;}

   public static implicit operator EntityX(EntityXModel x){
       return new EntityX {Name = X.Name};
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it is very very time consuming. However the real problem comes into the play when dealing with SOAP services where those models are auto-generated in a serializable manner and we need to to often update the service reference.

What is the best approach to add such validation attributes to both EF entity classes and SOAP service models?